# Получить размеры активной области родителя фрейма

Tags: javascript, html, css

Родитель фрейма и фрейм имеют разные домены из за этого получить доступ к родителю из фрейма не позволяет безопасность. Можно ли как то получить хотя бы высоту окна страницы в которой находится фрейм?

Внимание! Получить нужно эти данные из фрейма и так же родитель фрейма не мой и ничего с ним делать не могу НО нужно адаптировать фрейм под эту страницу по этому нужна как минимум высота окна. Буду очень благодарен если подскажите хоть какой-то вариант получения нужных мне данных.

так же мне нужна не вся высота body а только 100vh в пикселях

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во фрейме можно попробовать ```window.outerHeight```

Comment: Это было под носом все время и я не обращал на это внимания =) Большое спасибо